# brochure website name with empty space on both sides

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Website has different names like, `One page website`, `slider website`, How do you call a website which has empty space on both side and the website is on middle , `It is kind of one page (no scroll bar)` that tells everything about the company, I want to know how do you call it ?

Here is an example of what I am saying

[Example 1](http://elogix.mintithemes.com/#!prettyPhoto)

[Example 2](http://demo.hb-themes.com/?theme=Aegaeus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of Web page/Website layouts:

1. Boxed layout
2. Stretched Layout

And you are looking for Boxed layout.

Hope this helps.